# AppArmor: How to block pid=host container with CAP_SYS_ADMIN/CAP_SYS_CHROOT from reading (some) host files?

Tags: linux-capabilities, linux-namespaces, apparmor

Given is a container that has `pid=host` (so it is in the initial PID namespace and has a full view on all processes). This container (rather, its process) additionally has the capabilities `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` and `CAP_SYS_CHROOT`, so it can change mount namespaces using `setns(2)`.

- Is it possible using AppArmor to block this container from accessing arbitrary files in the host (the initial mount namespace), except for some files, such as `/var/run/foo`?
- How does AppArmor evaluate filesystem path names with respect to mount namespaces? Does it "ignore" mount namespaces and just take the specified path, or does it translate a path, for instance when dealing with bind-mounted subtrees, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ingrained restriction of AppArmor's architecture is that in case of filesystem resources (files, directories) it mediates access using the access path. While AppArmor uses labeling, as does SELinux, AppArmor *derives* only *implicit* filesystem resource labels from the access path. In contrast, SELinux uses *explicit* labels which are stored in the extended attributes of files on filesystems supporting POSIX extended attributes.

Now, the access path always is the path as seen in the caller's current mount namespace. Optionally, AppArmor can take chroot into account. So the answer to the second question item is: AppArmor "ignores" mount namespaces and just takes the (access) path. It does not translate the bind mounts, as far as I understand (there's nowhere any indication to be seen it would do).

As for the first question item: in general "no", due to AppArmor mediating access path (labels), not file resource labels. A limited access restriction is possible when accepting that there won't be any access path differentiation between what's inside a container and what's in the host outside the container (same for what's inside other containers). This is basically what [Docker's default container AppArmor profile](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/apparmor/template.go) does: restricting all access to a few highly sensitive /proc/ entries and restricting to read-only access for many other /proc/ entries.

But blocking access to certain host file access paths always comes with the danger of blocking the same access path for a perfectly valid use inside a container (different mount namespace), so this requires great care, lots of research and testing, as well as the constant danger of things breaking in the next update of a container. [AppArmor seems to not be designed for such usecases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66296100).